# Previously approved site was disapproves with "Insufficient Content" why?

Tags: adsense

This makes no sense at all..

The site has MORE content since it was originally approved in December, close to 100 blogs now in fact.

Why are google rejecting it as insufficient content?

The privacy policy was put in at the start.

Any ideas? website is adamharkus.com

Thank you for your interest in Google AdSense. Unfortunately, after reviewing your application, we're unable to accept you into AdSense at this time.
We did not approve your application for the reasons listed below.

Insufficient content:

To be approved for AdSense and show relevant ads on your site, your pages need to have enough text on them for our specialists to review and for our crawler to be able to determine what your pages are about. 
To resolve this issue, please work through the following suggestions: 
Make sure that your pages have sufficient text – websites that contain mostly images, videos or Flash animations will not be approved.
Your content should contain complete sentences and paragraphs, not only headlines.
Ensure that your website is fully built and launched before you apply for AdSense – do not apply while your site’s still in a beta or “under construction” phase or only consists of a website template.
Place the ad code on a live page of your website. It does not have to be the main page, but test pages that are empty except for the AdSense ad code will not be approved.
Provide a clear navigation system for your visitors so that they can easily find all of the sections and pages of your website.
If you’d like to monetise YouTube videos, please apply for the YouTube monetisation program. Note that blogs and websites that contain only videos will not be approved

Comment: Voting to close because question not about programming and should be asked from AdSense

Comment: I've tried, and i noticed there was an "adsense" tag so why not ask? I'm sure others have had the same issue. Advice would be helpful all-round.

Comment: Please read the help section. Tag names don't mean you can ask about anything, it has to be about programming. And we cannot comment on AdSense's decisions, only they can.

Comment: Point taken. Thank you.